# Don't need progress bar appear while process running in background in Mac Word

Tags: macos, ms-word, progress-bar

I have developed an office 365 add-in which has two long process which run on the load one after the other. When I have long word document like 175 pages it shows progress bar twice because of two processes run in the background. Is there a way to disable the feature of progress bar appearance? Actually I don't want to see this progress bar again and again.

```
var productUrl = businessLogic.appSettings().ProductUrl;
        businessLogic.getProduct(productUrl)
            .then(function () {
                businessLogic.getNumOfPages()
                    .then(function (data) {
                        businessLogic.getProductOptions(productUrl)
                            .then(function () {
                                businessLogic.checkIfAllPageSizesAreLetterSize(false);
                                getOptionsPackages();
                            });
                    });
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                businessLogic.error(error);
            });
```

First time progress bar appear on this call:

businessLogic.getNumOfPages()//it traverse from first to last page

Second time it appear on this call:

businessLogic.checkIfAllPageSizesAreLetterSize(false);//This call also make the control traverse from first to last page

Comment: Can we see an extract of the relevant code please?

Comment: @bated find my code below and instruct on this please

Comment: Please edit your question and put the code there.  Adding it as an answer will result in it being deleted.